# PDO Connection : row count using where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to count the no of rows in my database..along with where clause and AND clause..

please show me how can we do that in pdo..

these are my queries:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * from questions  where (category_id = ?) AND (complexity_id = ?) ORDER BY RAND()");

$stmt->execute(array($_POST['category'],$_POST['complexity'])); 
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

count:

$nRows = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions");
```

i need to write both queries in one query only..

Comment: Keep in mind if one day the number of questions you have grows very large this query might cause problems since it's unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If your queries are different

If your queries are *different*, like it shown in the question, then keep them as two separate queries. There is no way to get them in one. Just leave it two separate queries, it's all right.

#### If your queries actually the same

If your queries actually the same, and you want to get your data filtered and also get the number of rows, then you don't need the second query at all. In PHP, there is a function called count(). You can use it to count results returned by your first query.

```
$nRows = count($data);
```

as simple as that

Comment: but i when i use like that it's not working as per my requirement

Comment: WHAT ARE your requirements? Read my updated answer and for goodnes sake tell what case is yours

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fetchColumn`.

```
 $number_of_rows=$stmt->fetchColumn(); // will give no. of rows
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)// give the data array
```

Comment: i want to use count query also in above query..but when i use count it display error..can you please tell me how can we use count query..

Comment: `fetchColumn(); `  will give the count what else you want.

Comment: ya..what you said is right..but i would like  to use COUNT only..because by using count i need to hide my button value..that's why..

Comment: see here:https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/can-i-use-select-count-in-pdo/238774/3

Answer (score -1):

Can you just use

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) from questions  where (category_id = ?) AND (complexity_id = ?)");
```

query?

Comment: don't know it's giving error Undefined property: stdClass: